# How to fix div on scrolling when distance is > 100 using jquery and css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I do scroll down after, after it reach 100px, it will add the class to the div. Then by using css I add the `top:50px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your delete button is maybe overlaying the container, i.e. it's a z-index issue. Does adding a sufficiently high z-index to .fixed-content help?

```
.fixed-content {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

If not, can you post some of the surrounding HTML so we can create a fiddle and see/troubleshoot the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the div after scrolling distance is > 100px:

```
<div id="header"></div>

<style>
#header {
  background-color: #f90;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#header.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
</style>

<script>
function header_sticky() {
    var header = document.getElementById( 'header' );
    if ( window.scrollY >= 100 ) {
        header.className = 'sticky';
    } else {
        header.className = '';
    }
}
window.addEventListener( 'load', header_sticky, false );
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', header_sticky, false );
</script>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/svitch/pen/vebeBB)